# PHP test if form has file uploaded

Tags: php, forms

How do I do it? These don't work:

```
if(empty($_FILES)){
  echo "there is no file uploaded";
  exit;
} else {
  echo "there is file";
}

if(sizeof($_FILES)!=0){
  echo "there is file";
} else {
  echo "there is no file";
}
```

Comment: `if (count($_FILES) > 0) { }`

Comment: Did you check for [the post max size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#100728)? Also, make sure your form is set to POST and not GET.

Comment: @Dale, that will always return false somehow.

Comment: not if you manage to get the file uploaded it won't :-)

Comment: you're not using method="get" are you? ;-)

Comment: See Baba's answer... Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

Sample :

```
<?php

if (isset ( $_FILES ['image'] )) {
    if ($_FILES ["image"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "File Was Uploaded AND OK";
    } else {
        echo "File Was Uploaded but BAD";
    }
} else {
    echo "No File Uploaded";
}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename 1:</label> <input type="file" name="image"
        id="file" /> <br /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You can see more examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. I wanted to test if the user didn't submit the file even though there is a file input.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

"If $_FILES is empty ... try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag and make sure you have file uploads turned on."

Comment: I have that. not working. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use is_array($_FILES) to check if it contains files info in array format or not